# How to use `awk` so that i can alter only one or two fields in the line conditionally?

Tags: awk

I have a tab separated file with 16 fields.  Can i use `awk` to conditionally alter one one or fields and print the whole line as the output? e.g., depending on value in the first field, i want to say add a specific number to field 4 and so on. But as a output i have to print the whole line. If yes, i would like to know how.

Comment: Yes, you can. Do you also need some help with the how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, here's an approach:

```
awk '$1 == "ALTER" { $5=$5+5 } 1'
```

With etuardu's sample file, this produces

```
ALTER xx yy zz 15 10
NOALT aa bb cc 20 20
ALTER 11 22 33 35 30
```

Here's how it works. There are two cases, expressed as awk patterns and actions. In the first, the pattern is a test of the first field to see if it equals `"ALTER"`, invoking the action that modifies the fifth field if the pattern evaluates to true. The second pattern is that final `1`; it's always true, so the implicit `print` action is performed.

One quirk with this solution: the field separators read in the input need not be those in the output. With the simple form above, the field separators from the inputs are taken to be whitespace, while single spaces are written to the output; set `FS` and `OFS` to specific values if that isn't what you want. However, only lines where a field is changed will have the new field separators, so a null op like '$1=$1' will force all records to be rebuilt (this is a convenient way to change field separators, by only using `$1=$1`).

Comment: The 'quirk' is also a problem in the other two answers, so I wouldn't hold it against this one. Great answer (although I would call the 'conditions' 'actions'.)

Comment: @schot Yes, that quirk is present in pretty much any solution to this, but I thought it worth mentioning as it is not obvious here. I'll adjust the text to use the standard awk terminology of patterns and actions; I hope you'll give it another look.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber You made a great answer even better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is an example of use (perhaps not the smartest):

```
etuardu@subranu:~$ cat sample.txt 
ALTER xx yy zz 10 10
NOALT aa bb cc 20 20
ALTER 11 22 33 30 30
etuardu@subranu:~$ awk '{ if ($1=="ALTER") print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5+1,$6-1; else print $0 }' sample.txt 
ALTER xx yy zz 11 9
NOALT aa bb cc 20 20
ALTER 11 22 33 31 29
```

Please refer to `man awk` or some online tutorial (there are plenty) for more informations.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I know this solution.  Its just that i dont want to type in print $1,$2....$32 etc.  I am looking for a less type intensive solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about this (file sample taken from @etuardu)-

```
awk '{if($1=="ALTER") {$5=$5+1;print"\n";for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf $i" ";} else print "\n"$0}' input_file | sed '/^$/d'
```

- Check for the specific line to alter using the if statement.
- If the expected field found then make the alterations eg. $5=$5+1 …
  so on and so forth.
- Run a for loop by repeating the loop based on number of fields.
- Print the fields which would include the updated fields.
- If the expected field is not found run the else loop.
- sed will remove any blank lines that has been created due to new lines.

Sample:

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat text8
NOALT aa bb cc 20 20
ALTER xx yy zz 10 10
ALTER xx yy zz 10 10
NOALT aa bb cc 20 20
ALTER 11 22 33 30 30

[jaypal~/Temp]$ awk '{if($1=="ALTER") {$5=$5+1;print"\n";for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf $i" ";} else print "\n"$0}' text8 | sed '/^$/d'
NOALT aa bb cc 20 20
ALTER xx yy zz 11 10 
ALTER xx yy zz 11 10 
NOALT aa bb cc 20 20
ALTER 11 22 33 31 30
```